# Keep laptop plugged in if at full charge if battery is not removable?

Tags: laptop, battery

I just bought a new laptop and it comes with an integrated battery. For these types of laptops, is it better to leave the plug when fully charged or not ?

I ve just experienced an issue, i looked at the power indicator and it was orange meaning it was charging but I only used the laptop without the plug 2 days ago when I bought it to fully discharge it, then I fully charged it. It reached 100 percent and since then I had it plugged. So it was weird to see the orange lught since it was on plug, when I checked status it said 97 percent showing it as plugged but saying 'not charging'. After a google search and performing various things I found online I was ready to update the BIOS but first I tried to discharge it for a while. At 50 percent I plugged again and suddenly it recognized it as charging.
Now, I dont know if it is a windows 10 issue or it is the battery.

In any case, what should I do? Leave it plugged or not? (remember battery is not removable)

Also, any tip on that issue I had? Is it windows or battery ? (I have until tomorrow to get the laptop replaced, after that is service)

Thanks.

Notebook is HP m6 014dx

Comment: Now it is happening again, after trying at 50 percent, I fully discharged it again and turned off to fully charge it, I came back some hours later and saw the orange light so I thought it was weird and that it wasnt charging, so turned it on and it was 98 percent (19 minutes to fully charge), looked somewhere else and when I look again (no more than 1 minute later) it said 100 percent fully charged and light turned white. Did not unplug it, now I check and says 99 percent not charging but shows like it is plugged, when unplug it goes to 98 and when plug goes at 99. WEIRD

Comment: Now it is at 97 unplugged saying 5hs left, 2 minutes later it says 7 hours 47 minutes left. I guess windows is the problem. But I dont know.

Comment: I would see to it that it is being charged as few times as possible. Many batteries have counters and e.g. after 100 charges they drop dead on you.

Comment: Batteries + Windows = Never accurate. I wouldn't take anything displayed about battery life as gospel but its a fairly accurate counter. Don't forget, the more things you do on your laptop -> The quicker the battery will run out. As for it being integrated, it won't make any difference with regards to how long it will last and how you should treat it. Batteries eventually die out and slowly become less and less efficient. The less charges you perform, the better.

Comment: @AaronLayfield Hi, yes it might be a windows issue since I made another test and checked to see how last it longed and it was probably 7 hours (I was sleeping, though). Initiated count at 23.02 pm, woke up at 5.30 or so and it was still on, displaying the msg of low battery, I fell asleep again an next time I woke up it was off (8.55). So it last roughly 7 hrs I guess (advertising 7hs 45min) of course it was doing nothing, just chrome open, max brightness, no backlit ketyboard.

Comment: @AaronLayfield When you say the less charges the better, thats the thing I dont get with integrated batteries, for the removable Ive read that it is better to take them out and use plug only, but I cant with this one. So if I leave the plug it still counts as charging the battery? What about the reason why it is better to take out the battery (heat), how this issue applies to non removable batteries? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You said you just bought this laptop, which means it is **under warranty**. I would suggest you contact the manufacturer for support, rather than ask us for 2 reasons; 1) *They can help you determine if there is actually something wrong with it and get you fixed. You may inadvertently void your warranty if you continue to mess with it.* 2) *Our advice here is just that; it is advice. Not being able to physically troubleshoot your equipment leave us with only suggestions. There is a chance we may unintentionally mislead you based on what you have told, or not told, us.*

Comment: @CharlieRB Hi, thanks. It just happens i am from South America, and you dont usually get models like these sold here , so you buy them from shops, not directly hp and these people buy them overseas. And I am fairly sure most are refurbs. In fact, when using hp website to download BIOS update a msg appeared saying warranty expired on Jan 10 (even though the seller advertised the product as having original warranty, which I already knew it wasnt true since they said 6 months, and original warranty is at least a year. But you know, If I wanted to buy this model here, had to take the risk)